# Is this a Muehlenbeckia?

Tags: identification, houseplants, ornamental-plant

I got this as a gift a few years back, and I am still unsure of its name. It has darker green leaves which are purple on the underside and shaped into a point. It has no thorns. It is very frail, segments break off easily. It is also very easy to propagate it, since the broken segments can just be put it into soil and quickly grow roots. I kept it both in shade and on a sunlit shelf and it doesn't seem to care. I water it when the soil gets dry, but a bit too much or too little water does not seem to hurt it. It hasn't blossomed yet. Older parts of the plant dry off and fall off. It looks like [Muehlenbeckia complexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muehlenbeckia_complexa), but the leaves are pointy, so I am not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a **callisia** (https://worldofsucculents.com/callisia-repens-turtle-vine/) that was not in direct light. It can change from almost succulent to very thin leaves.

The leaves should be around 1 cm in size.

Comment: I think this is correct, but its hard to tell.